# Batch normalization imlementation on intel MKL failed

Tags: intel-mkl, batch-normalization

I'm trying to implement a simple batch normalization call using Intel MKL, I couldn't find an example online so I tried to follow the logicall structure of intel MKL code, However, I got this error

```
makefile:151: recipe for target '_results/bn_layer_generator_mkl.res' failed
make[1]: *** [_results/bn_layer_generator_mkl.res] Error 255
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tiramisu/benchmarks/DNN/layers/bn/cpu'
makefile:82: recipe for target 'libintel64' failed
make: *** [libintel64] Error 2
[bn_layer_generator_mkl.c:84] err (-1)
FAILED
```

I previously implemented other intel MKL functions ( convolution, ReLu ) and I could run them correctly.
Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong with batch normalization?
Here is my code

```
dnnError_t err;

size_t outputSize[dimension] = {N, N, FIn, BATCH_SIZE};
size_t outputStrides[dimension] = {1, N, N * N, N * N * FIn};

size_t inputSize[dimension] = {N, N, FIn, BATCH_SIZE};
size_t inputStrides[dimension] = {1, N, N * N, N * N * FIn};

dnnLayout_t lt_user_input = NULL,
            lt_user_output = NULL;
dnnLayout_t lt_bn_input = NULL,
            lt_bn_output = NULL;
dnnPrimitive_t cv_user_to_bn_input = NULL,
               cv_bn_to_user_output = NULL;
dnnPrimitive_t bn = NULL;
double *resBn1[dnnResourceNumber] = {0};
dnnPrimitiveAttributes_t attributes = NULL;

double *user_i = NULL,
       *user_o = NULL;

/*** data allocation ***/
user_i = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * (N * N * FIn * BATCH_SIZE));
if (user_i == NULL)
{
    err = E_MEMORY_ERROR;
    goto bail_out;
}

/*** User's data description ***/
CHECK_ERR(dnnLayoutCreate_F64(&lt_user_input, dimension, inputSize, inputStrides), err);
CHECK_ERR(dnnLayoutCreate_F64(&lt_user_output, dimension, outputSize, outputStrides), err);

/* Initialize attributes */
CHECK_ERR(dnnPrimitiveAttributesCreate_F64(&attributes), err);

/*** Bn section ***/
CHECK_ERR(dnnBatchNormalizationCreateBackwardData_F64(&bn, attributes, lt_user_input, -0.01), err);

CHECK_ERR(dnnLayoutCreateFromPrimitive_F64(&lt_bn_input, bn, dnnResourceSrc), err);
CHECK_ERR(dnnLayoutCreateFromPrimitive_F64(&lt_bn_output, bn, dnnResourceDst), err);
CHECK_ERR(init_conversion(&cv_user_to_bn_input, &resBn1[dnnResourceSrc], lt_bn_input, lt_user_input, user_i), err);
CHECK_ERR(dnnAllocateBuffer_F64((void **)&resBn1[dnnResourceDst], lt_bn_output), err);
CHECK_ERR(init_conversion(&cv_bn_to_user_output, &user_o, lt_user_output, lt_bn_output, resBn1[dnnResourceDst]), err);

srand(1);

for (int i = 0; i < inputSize[0] * inputSize[1] * inputSize[2] * inputSize[3]; i++)
    user_i[i] = rand() % 10 - 5;

/*** Execution ***/
if (cv_user_to_bn_input)
    CHECK_ERR(dnnConversionExecute_F64(cv_user_to_bn_input, user_i, resBn1[dnnResourceSrc]), err);

CHECK_ERR(dnnExecute_F64(bn, (void *)resBn1), err);
```

Answer (score 0):

Deep Neural Network (DNN) component is deprecated and will be removed in the next Intel MKL release. We will continue to support provide optimized functions for deep neural networks in Intel Math Kernel Library for Deep Neural Networks (Intel MKL-DNN). This is Open source implementation available from hithub - https://github.com/intel/mkl-dnn. Please check how batch mode works with this lib.